# Overlaying Image Over Desktop

Tags: macos, cocoa, desktop

I was wondering if anyone knew how application's like shade and camouflage for mac programmatically lay an image over the desktop? How do they build an application that's not window based, but build into the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Windows do not necessarily have chrome. You can build an empty, transparent window with no bar, nor buttons or other controls. Then you can add any (half-transparent) image, control or other view on top of that.

Using `-[NSWindow setLevel:]` you can control where in regard to other windows the transparent window is displayed. You can draw under the desktop or over the menu bar, if you must.

Comment: Sorry to pest, fairly new at this. Do you mind showing a small example of positioning a window above the desktop, but behind the menubar/dock? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary
                         dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCGNormalWindowLevel],
                         NSFullScreenModeWindowLevel, nil];
[[window contentView] enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen]
                   withOptions:options];
```

Comment: How would you move this back levels?